# amazon ec2 and pointing subdomain

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subdomain

First of all thanks for reading.
Im a relative newbie to AWS and Domains and i have an issue pointing a subdomain to my amazon ec2 instance. Instance is running an EVE Online application (webserver)

Details;
Domain is registered to Godaddy - orco.space 
Name servers are godaddy Name servers

Domain is hosted on my 123-reg Hosting Package.
This domain works and i have been able to set up a forum on there.

I have created a subdomain on 123-reg of auth.orco.space and i want to point this to my amazon ec2 instance.

I have gone into Route 53 and created a public hosted zone. In that hosted zone i have put my elastic IP that i have associated to my instance however when i access the address i dont get anything coming back apart from server not found (in firefox).

Is there anything else i need to do as when ichanged the nameservers in godaddy to the amazon nameservers i lose access to my forum.

Any help would be apprecated. TIA

Comment: did you installed/started any webserver inside the ec2 instance and made it listen the 80 port? (*in case that port is the one you use*)

Comment: Hope this could help: https://www.cloudassessments.com/blog/configure-dns-with-route-53/

Comment: Thanks for the help here guys, i realized after some playing around that that sub domain was not going to link from my hosting to AWS.
But also that AWS by default does not allow port 80 access in route 53 securoity groups. Once i had changed the security group and set it my main domain it worked.